Cypress code to move a range selector from one place to another is not working
I have a cypress code which moves the range selector from one place to another. It selects range selector position properly but it doesn't move the range selector
This is the command file
Cypress.Commands.add('dragRangeSelectorTo', (bottomAxisPoint) => {
cy.get('.chart-layout__x-axis .tick')
.contains(bottomAxisPoint)
.invoke('attr', 'transform')
.then((requiredPointAttribute) => {
if (requiredPointAttribute) {
const requiredPointPosition = parseFloat(requiredPointAttribute.split('(')[1].split(',')[0].trim());
    // Get the third .range-selector-move-interactor element
    cy.get('.range-selector-move-interactor').eq(1).then($selector => {
      const selectorPosition = $selector.position().left;
      let offsetValue = Math.ceil(requiredPointPosition - selectorPosition);
      offsetValue = offsetValue < 0 ? offsetValue - 10 : offsetValue + 10;

      cy.log(`Selector Position: ${selectorPosition}`);
      cy.log(`Offset Value: ${offsetValue}`);

      // Ensure the element is visible
      cy.get('.range-selector-move-interactor').eq(1)
        .should('be.visible')
         .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1, force: true }).click();

      // Simulate realistic mouse movement
      cy.get('body').trigger('mousemove', {
        clientX: selectorPosition + offsetValue,
        clientY: $selector.position().top, // Use the top position for vertical movement
        force: true
      });

      // Release the mouse button
      cy.get('body').trigger('mouseup', { force: true }).click();

      // Ensure that the drag has been successful
      cy.get('.range-selector-move-interactor').eq(1).then($newSelector => {
        const newPosition = $newSelector.position().left;
        cy.log(`New Position: ${newPosition}`);
        expect(newPosition).not.to.eq(selectorPosition);
      });
    });
  }
});

});
And the this is the error am getting
expected 444.65625 to not equal 444.65625

What is the HTML of the page you are testing?

Not html its a angular site

What do you mean "not html"? There must be html, it's running in a browser.

I suggest you add the package cypress-real-events to the project, and substitute cy.real***() commands for the built-in Cypress commands.
By the way, adding .click() after .trigger() would not be recommended and may be causing your issues.
cy.get('.range-selector-move-interactor').eq(1)
  .should('be.visible')
  .realMouseDown() // perform a native mouse press on the field
  .realMouseMove(selectorPosition + offsetValue)
  .realMouseUp()

